# Java android get file from /mnt/media_rw/

Tags: java, android

I want to get file from usb storage when I check this:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY && Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED
```

I have got false , how I can get a files. when I use a ES File Explorer and accept a usb connection permission I can read this file

Answer (score 0):

Get permission for read external storage

```
String externalStorage=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(externalStorage)){
    //do anything
 }else{
  // show error message
 }
```